# icon are not showing in font awesome html

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I was working was HTML5 and CSS for making a personal portfolio website and I needed to use font awesome icons.
some of them work but other not I tried every thing possible I googled it and I watched YouTube tutorials and I searched on stack over flow and all of them were useless so can any body help me

this is the full Css file and html file

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
:root{
    --color-dark-blue:#0C2D48;
    --color-white-blue:#B1D4E0;
    --color-light-blue:#2E8BC0;
    --color-mid-blue:#145DA0;
    --color-purple-blue:#c0c1c2;
    
    
}
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;     
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
header{
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 15;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 200px;
}
.logo-txt{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #3a6cf4;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.navigation a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3a6cf4;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.navigation a:hover{
    color: #0b41d4;
    font-weight: 600;
}
section{
    padding: 100px 200px;
}
.main-sec{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: url("images/test15.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.main-sec h2{
    color: #4e9eff;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.main-sec h3{
    color: var(--color-purple-blue);
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.main-btn{
    color: white;
    background-color: #3a6cf4;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.937em 2.187em;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    transition: 0.7s ease;
}
.main-btn:hover{
    background-color: #0a49f6;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.social-icons a{
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
.title{
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center ;
    color:#0a49f6 ;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    font-weight: 800;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.content{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}
.card{
    background-color: white;
    width: 21.5em;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(1, 1, 1, 15%);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 15px;
}
.card:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: 0.7s ease;
}
.icon{
    color: #3a6cf4;
    font-size: 8em;
    text-align: center;
}
.info{
    text-align: center;
}

.info h3{
    color: #3a6cf4;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ABF</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo-txt">abf</a>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <a href="#" class="services">services</a>
            <a href="#" class="projects">projects</a>
            <a href="#" class="contact">contact</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
    <section class="main-sec">
        <div>
            <h2>Web devoloper</h2>
            <h3>I build front end websites</h3>
            <a href="#projects" class="main-btn">View my work</a>
            <div class="social-icons">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>v         

    <sectionn class="cards" id="services">
        <h2 class="title">services</h2>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">

                    <i class="fa-solid fa-display-code"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3>front-end</h3>
                    <p>
                        making proffesional front-end structure for
                        websites with different topics
                        using html and css
                    </p>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">

                    <i class="fa-solid fa-photo-film"></i> 
                    
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3>motion graphic</h3>
                    <p>
                        making proffesional motion graphic
                        videos using illustrator and after
                        effects
                    </p>
                </div>
                
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">

                    <i class="fa-solid fa-layer-group"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3>photo design</h3>
                    <p>
                        making proffesional advertising desings
                        using illustrator and photoshop
                    </p>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I Google searched and cannot find fa-display-code but can find for example fa-photo-file. Do you have a reference link which mentions display file?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.social-icons{
  color:white
}
```

The icons are there, they're just white-on-white.

Comment: no bro the social icons proberty is for the social icons that are shown the one that iam exactly talking about is the frond-end icon that is not shown

Comment: You should make that clear in your post then.  I don't know why that particular icon isn't showing up - it looks like the CSS isn't specifying a :before element like it is with the other icons.  I suggest posting a bug report with FontAwesome.

Comment: @amrbassem You should update the details on your question, not just comment in all answer like this. And make sure that you are able to use Font Awesome Pro. Because that icon is [only for pro](https://fontawesome.com/icons/display-code?s=solid)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in connected lib, i think u need write for fa about this bug.  Try this lib for fix problem https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.0/css/all.css

Comment: the social icons proberty stands for the social icons wich are shown an fine what i talk about is the front-end icon which is not shown

Comment: Try to connect this lib https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.0/css/all.css

Comment: if it help, vote for others